# C# Generic method param

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to create a simple service where derived classes can override a virtual method by passing in its own objects. Cant seem to get the syntax right. Please see the codes below:

So the base class is as follows:

```cs
public class FooBase
{
    public virtual Task StartFooAsync<TParam>(TParam param) where TParam : IFooParam
    {
        Console.WriteLine(param.GetType());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And the `IFooParam` interface:

```cs
public interface IFooParam
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And the class that implements this simple interface is:

```cs
public class FooParam : IFooParam
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I try to inherit the FooBase class as:

```cs
public class FooOne : FooBase
{
   public override Task StartFooAsync(FooParam param) // wont compile :(
   {
       return base.StartFooAsync(param);
   }
}
```

I get compile time error telling me there's no suitable method to override for `StartFooAsync`

The goal here is to inherit from the `FooBase` class and provide own implementation with its preferred type as parameter for `StartFooAsync`

Comment: When overriding a member the signature must stay **exactly the same**. So either override it including the generic constraint, or make your **base-class** generic and your class implementing deriving from that base-class with a concrete type-argument: `class FooOne : FooBase<FooParam> { ... }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if the virtual method is a generic method, the override has to be as well. A generic method allows the *caller* to specify the type argument.

Here's an example of why your code can't work... this should be entirely valid:

```cs
class OtherParam : IFooParam
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

FooBase x = new FooOne(); // FooOne derives from FooBase
var p = new OtherParam { Title = "xyz" };
x.StartFooAsync<OtherParam>(p);
```

There's nothing in the declaration of `FooBase` that would stop that from compiling... but you haven't provided an implementation of `StartFooAsync` that can handle `OtherParam`.

One alternative approach is to make `FooBase` generic instead:

```cs
public class FooBase<TParam> where TParam : IFooParam
{
    public virtual Task StartFooAsync(TParam param)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then your `FooOne` would derive from `FooBase<FooParam>`. That would prevent the broken code I showed before, because `x` would to be declared as either `FooBase<FooParam>` or `FooOne`, and the `StartFooAsync` method would *only* accept `FooParam`.